# Make Mathematica evaluate an integral symbolically

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

The following integral has a symbolic solution, which MMA does not return.

$\kappa(x) \begin{cases}
\text{mod}(x,1)\le0.5: & 1\\ 
\text{mod}(x,1)>0.5: & 0
\end{cases}$

$f(z)=\int_0^1 \kappa(x+z)\kappa(x) \text{d} x$

$\kappa$ is a periodic indicator function, the integral gives the two-point correlation function. It can be expressed as

$f(z)=(0.5 - z) \kappa(z) - (0.5 - z) (1 - \kappa(z))$.

The output to

```
ID[x_] = Boole[Mod[x, 1] < 0.5]
Integrate[ID[z + x] ID[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

is just the unevaluated input integral. How can I add the integration rules such that I get the desired output? (Using `Piecewise` does not work)

## Edit 1

The above example works only for the value 0.5 and `0<z<1`. Changing the 0.5 everywhere breaks the solution. But using Assumptions solve the problem:

```
ID[x_] = UnitStep[-Mod[x,1] + 1/3]
Integrate[ID[z + x] ID[x], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < z < 1}]
```

Gives

```
Piecewise[{{(1/3)*(1 - 3*z), 0 < z < 1/3}, {(1/3)*(-2 + 3*z), 2/3 < z < 1}}, 0]
```

which is what I need.

## Edit 2

Without restricting $0<z<1$, the solution is obtained by replacing `z->Mod[z]` after integrating with assumptions. One could try to implement this integration rule.

```
ID[x_] = UnitStep[-Mod[x, 1] + 1/2];
Integrate[ID[z+x]ID[x],{x,0,1},Assumptions->{0<z<1}]/.{z->Mod[z,1]}
Plot[{ID[z],%}, {z,-1,2}]
```

[image: Indicator function and two point correlation, both periodic]

Comment: $z$ is a real number?

Comment: yes, everything is real

Comment: Using `UnitStep` instead of `Boole` you can evaluate the indefinite integral.

Comment: The analytic solution isn't correct I think.

Comment: The analytic solution appears to be correct, but I may have missed some fine points. The problem seems to be `mod`, it does also not work with `UnitStep`.

Comment: ok, the analytic solution is only correct in the range `0<z<1`

Comment: <s>Yes, with the Assumption it works!</s>